# reproduce libc++/libstdc++ ABI incompatibility on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, macos, c++11, libc++

A friend of mine and I are working on a project using C++11. He is using OS X and I am using Linux.

As `libc++` and `libstdc++` are not ABI-compatibel, we have to make sure not to mix the up between our libraries and our application.

However we currently have linker issue caused by mixing `libc++` and `libstdc++` and I want to try figure out, from which libraries it's caused.

Ideally I would like to do it at home, but as I don't own a mac and I don't want to pay multiple hundreds of dollars just for one bugfix I would like to try to reproduce the issue it on my linux system.

Comment: Note that issues could also come from libc++abi / libsupc++ (i.e. one step lower).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appereantly Mac OS X is the [only platform](http://libcxx.llvm.org/#requirements) with full libc++ support.

A Windows and a Linux port are currently on their way, but are not fully functional [yet](http://libcxx.llvm.org/#dir-structure) *(2013-07-18)*

However, down below build instructions for Linux do exist, which I am going to try out.

Comment: Some linux distributions (debian for instance) have a libc++ package.